# CSS - is there a cousin selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Suppose I have the following table ([JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y9b3q/2/)):

```
<table class="data-table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Method</th>
        <th scope="col">Price</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Pickup*</td>
        <td>no charge</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Campus mail</td>
        <td>no charge</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">* At 1st floor desk</td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

The rows of the TBODY have been zebra striped using an :nth-child(2n) selector.  But the background of the row in the TFOOT doesn't get those styles, and breaks the even/odd striping any time the table has an even number of rows in the TBODY.

I'd like to select the TFOOT row with something like `.data-table tbody tr:nth-child(2n):last-child + tr`, but that won't work.  The `+` selector is for adjacent sibling elements that share a single parent element.  The two TRs here aren't siblings, they're cousins.

I *could* use jQuery (something like `$(".data-table tbody tr:nth-child(2n):last-child").parent().next().find("tr").css({"background-color": "blue"})`).  But I'd prefer a CSS solution if there is one.

So, is there any way to select an element's cousin?

Comment: Can you just move the tfoot row into the body?

Comment: Except it doesn't belong there... but I'm probably being too picky with semantics by saying that.

Comment: That would fix this table, but the CSS is for wider use on a site with a great many of these things.  I'll probably wind up fixing it with JS.

Comment: Would the CSS4 parent selector allow this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS works down the DOM (although selectors are processed backwards), so you can't navigate up an element tree and then back down to reach an element's cousin. You can only either operate on the same level of elements (only going forward), or go down.

You'll have to go with your jQuery solution.

Comment: Sigh.  I was afraid of that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Reference:
http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/PR-css3-selectors-20091215/#selectors

No, there are only decendant and limited sibling selectors.  You would have to use javascript to locate the element.