# Is it possible to select the child of my parent's sibling?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Am I able to select `.button` based on a pseudo-class of `.main`?

I want `div.button` to be blue only if `div.main` is empty (`.main:empty`). How can I do this using only CSS?

```
<div class="container">
<div class="header">
    <div class="button">I should have color:blue when .main is empty</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="main"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

*(please don't offer to solve using jQuery)*

Comment: I don't think you can get the content of an element using CSS, but I might be wrong...

Comment: @webeno I don't need the content of the element, but I can use :empty to select if it has nothing inside it. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/empty.html

Comment: Since there is no `parent` selector in CSS, this is not possible with CSS alone. The only way to do this would be if `.button` and `.main` were siblings.

Comment: Nope, can't be done without JavaScript. There's not parent, or previous sibling selector (yet).

Comment: Are you open to changing the HTML markup for this project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no way to select a "[cousin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930007/css-is-there-a-cousin-selector)" with pure CSS.

If `#header` were after `.content`, then you *could* select `.button` from a pseudo-class of `.content` -- an "aunt/uncle" -- using the adjacent sibling combinator (`+`) like this:

```
.content:hover + #header .button{/* styles */}
```

But even then, you're not able to select `.button` from a pseudo-class of `.main` (the "cousin")