# Is there a way to make my code functional without the label tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

I tried to create a show and hide action with CSS for the clear button and it worked perfectly only when I remove the label tag from around the input code. I am using materialize framework so the styling and functionality of the radio button depend on the label tag being present.
Here is the functioning code without the label tag and the materialize framework

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-content hoverable">
      <div>Institution challenges</div>
      <form>
        <div>
            <input id="acess-finance" name="culturalChallenges" value="FinancialAccess" type="radio" />
            <span>Access</span><br>
            <input id="infrastructure" name="culturalChallenges" value="infrastructure" type="radio" />
            <span>Infrastructure</span><br>
            <input id="Neglect"  name="culturalChallenges" value="govtNeglect" type="radio" />
            <span>Neglect</span><br>
            <input id="cultureFade"  name="culturalChallenges" value="cultureFade" type="radio" />
            <span>Fade </span><br>
        <div class="delSelc right-align">
          <input type="button" value="Clear selection" name="Clear" class="clearing" onclick="this.form.reset();shown();" />
        </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
/*CSS Code*/

.delSelc{
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

label > input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .delSelc,
label > input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .delSelc {
  opacity: 1;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

Here is the code with the materialize framework and the label tags included. This particular code ceases to be functional when the materialize framework is used.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-content hoverable">
      <div>Institution challenges</div>
      <form>
        <div>
         <label>
            <input id="acess-finance" name="culturalChallenges" 
            value="FinancialAccess" type="radio" />
            <span>Access</span>
         </label>
         <br>
          <label>
            <input id="infrastructure" name="culturalChallenges" 
            value="infrastructure" type="radio" />
            <span>Infrastructure</span>
         </label>
         <br>
       <label>
            <input id="Neglect" name="culturalChallenges" 
             value="Neglect" type="radio" />
            <span>Neglect</span>
            </label>
            <br>
        <label>
            <input id="cultureFade"  name="culturalChallenges" 
            value="cultureFade" type="radio" />
            <span>Fade </span>
        </label>
        <div class="delSelc right-align">
          <input type="button" value="Clear selection" name="Clear" 
          class="clearing" onclick="this.form.reset();shown();" />
        </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
<body>
```

```
/*CSS Code*/

.delSelc{
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

label > input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .delSelc,
label > input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .delSelc {
  opacity: 1;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

I tried using other frameworks like bootstrap but it didn't work either.

Is there any way around it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS - is there a cousin selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930007/css-is-there-a-cousin-selector)

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is targeting a direct descendent of a label

`label > input`

If the label is not there then there is nothing to match. Remove the `label >`  part of the selector

You will need another wrapper to make the ~ select the right elements that follow the checked modifier. Once the label is gone all delSelc elements will match as they follow the checked modifier. You could try a a span.

Comment: I edited the css and removed the `label >` and the code worked fine for the first code. I removed the label tag in the html  and also edited the css code to remove the `label >` for the second code which used the materialize framework but the tick effect for the radio button was not showing.